# Not able to view the data in a attachment in mail when sending the attachments from mfmailcomposer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In `MFMailComposer` I'm attaching an attachment. I send that attachment to another mail address.

In the destination mail that attachment are displayed with a download option and not with a view option.Actually that attachment is coming from a link. I don't know that attachment is `pdf` or `word` documents or any other. I need help, what to do?

I'm using this code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.fileString];
NSData *attachments = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[mailView addAttachmentData:attachments mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:self.useridString];
```

Comment: I think you cannot do this way, you need to download that file first into your documents directory and then attach that file in your MFMailComposer, hope it helps you

Comment: @prateek no, he downloaded it by creating an NSData object with the URL contents. However, I think the problem may be the unknown file format which possibly isn't PDF as you are telling in the mimeType attribute. Does the file type change or is it always the same?

Comment: Check your `url` and `attachments` having value or nil.

Answer (score 0):

Change in mimetype may be that will help you.

```
[mailView addAttachmentData:attachments mimeType:@"text/pdf" fileName:self.useridString];
```